# How to pass in mixin for template_name_field in Django TemplateView?

Tags: python, django, templates, view, mixins

I have a model using Django-MPTT that also has a field for using a specific template via the `template_name_field`. I'd like to be able to use a generic `TemplateView`, but pass in the mixin for using the `template_name_field`.

Here's the model:

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel
from mptt.fields import TreeForeignKey

class CategoryManager(models.Manager):
    def get(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        if 'full_slug' in defaults:
            if defaults['full_slug'] and defaults['full_slug'][-1] != "/":
                defaults['full_slug'] += "/"
        return super(CategoryManager, self).get(**defaults)

class Category(MPTTModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, help_text='A brief description of the category. No HTML allowed.')
    slug = models.SlugField(help_text='Prepopulates from title field.')
    full_slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    template_name = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True, help_text="Example: 'categories/category_parent.html'. If this isn't provided, the system will use 'categories/category_detail.html'.")

    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    objects = CategoryManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        orig_full_slug = self.full_slug
        if self.parent:
            self.full_slug = "%s%s/" % (self.parent.full_slug, self.slug)
        else:
        self.full_slug = "%s/" % self.slug
        obj = super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if orig_full_slug != self.full_slug:
            for child in self.get_children():
                child.save()
        return obj

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s (%s)" % (self.title, self.full_slug)
```

Here's the view:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.detail import SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed

from storefront.categories.models import Category

class SimpleCategoryView(TemplateView):

    def get_category(self):
        return Category.objects.get(full_slug=self.kwargs['full_slug'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SimpleCategoryView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["category"] = self.get_category()
        return context
```

And here's my URLS:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from storefront.categories.models import Category
from storefront.categories.views import CategoryView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<full_slug>[-\w/]+)', SimpleCategoryView.as_view(template_name='categories/category_detail.html'), name='category_view'),
```

),

How would I go about adding the mixin for using the `template_name_field` to my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a separate mixin. `TemplateView` already has the `TemplateResponseMixin`, so you can simply override `get_template_names` in your `SimpleCategoryView` subclass.

```
class SimpleCategoryView(TemplateView):
    ...
    def get_template_names(self):
        return [self.get_category().template_name]
```

Comment: Works, but how do I go about suppling an exception if `template_name` is None?

Comment: I figured it out `else: return ['categories/category_detail.html']`

Comment: FWIW, `get_template_names` returns a list of templates. Which means you can provide fallbacks. It will try each item in order and go with the first that matches an actual file.

Answer (score 0):

`DetailView` should have everything you need. You just need to tell `DetailView.get_template_names()` which field can contain a template name using the `template_name_field` attribute. Below is a full view definition that gets the `Category` based on the slug in the url. Note that the `Category` will be available in the template as both `object` and `category`.

```
class SimpleCategoryView(DetailView):
    model = Category
    slug_url_kwarg = 'full_slug'
    slug_field = 'full_slug'
    template_name_field = 'template_name'
```